# The devil is a discredited sociology professor in a simulated reality

Tags: story-identification, novel

The book starts out with the threat of an asteroid hitting Earth.  The hero and heroine find themselves in a café (or was it a bar? - the cover has a devil with a whiskey on the rocks if I remember correctly) with a demonic researcher (the character is a devil, who is an academic that was exiled for academic misconduct) who has a stone that allows him to tweak reality that could save the planet - ***if*** he gets additional stones.

The majority of the book is the hero and heroine are sent through different realities to get the stones from other exiles to create a more powerful artifact that had sufficient strength to solve the asteroid problem (rather than just winning on slot machines to fuel his drinking).  All of the realities are simulations in an academic computer system in a sociology department.

The book is on the older side. I think I was reading it in the late 80's from my father's library - so its not *newer* than that, though could have been published any time prior to that (if I was forced to guess, I'd say from the 70s, but that's a guess).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Jack Chalker, [*And The Devil Will Drag You Under*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/584395.And_the_Devil_Will_Drag_You_Under) published 1979.

Cover text:

> The end of the world was coming, and only a drunken demon could save
>   it... if he sobered up and if he could acquire, by means fair or foul,
>   five magic jewels.

[image]